# Regexp_filter on specific field of Sphinx Index?

Tags: regex, sphinx

I have been using `regexp_fitler` to good effect in my `Sphinx` configurations, however as far as I know it applies to the entire index in my select.

If my select for `idx_example` is:

`Select Name,Description,City,State from TableA`

and I do a regexp_filter e.g.

`NY > New York`

I can run into issues in for instance the `Description` field. I realize I can solve this with more complex patterns however given that the `State` fields I am getting are either Acronyms for Full-Names there is no reason to IF I can somehow force the `regexp_filter` to act only upon the `State` field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no offical syntax for it. One of hte main problems is how would sphinx apply it to queries. Would be difficult to apply it consistently.

It could be done with mysql functions, but would get cumbersome, if applying a large list.

```
 sql_query = Select Name,Description,City,REPLACE('NY','New Your',State) as State \
    FROM TableA
```

Wonder if could instead implemented it via a join, have a table of 'expansions'

```
short,full
NY,   New York
CA,   California
```

Then

```
sql_query = Select Name,Description,City,coalesce(e.full,State) as State \
   FROM TableA LEFT JOIN expansion e ON (state=short)
```

(make sure there is an index on expansion.short!)

Comment: Thanks, that would circumvent other work I am doing. Plan is to now store the entire html and use either zones or regexp with the tags to be specific about the mapping. Was hoping to avoid that.